# How to let a SqlDataSource use a list of numbers in SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Using asp.net I have a dropdown control on page that I want to use in my `SqlDataSource` without code behind.

My sql is

```
...WHERE ColumnID in (@Columns)
```

First values in dropdown are 1,3,4,5, so I want my SQL to become

```
..WHERE ColumnID in (1, 3, 4, 5)
```

Here is my control parameter

```
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlColumns"  Name="Columns" Type="String" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
</SelectParameters>
```

I get an error :

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '1,2,3,4,5' to data type int.

So it seems to be quoting

```
...WHERE ColumnID in ('1,3,4,5')
```

Is there anyway to tell it to not quote or to bypass (trick) it into working?

Comment: Can you show me `asp:DropDownList` and `asp:SqlDataSource` control you have (including code-behind method for them)? AFAIK that `WHERE IN` clause can be set during `SelectedIndexChanged` event of the `DropDownList` using an array, but I want to see how `DropDownList` bound to `GridView` first.

Comment: <telerik:RadDropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlColumns">
<Items>
<telerik:DropDownListItem Text="ALL" Value="1,2,3,4,5" />
<telerik:DropDownListItem Text="PAT" Value="1" />
</Items>
</telerik:RadDropDownList>

Comment: <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gv1" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" />
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultDataBaseServer %>"  SelectCommand="
SELECT * FROM TableData 
WHERE ColumnID in (@Columns)
">
<SelectParameters>
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlColumns"  Name="Columns" Type="String" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>

Comment: I found that you can keep the string exception silent by setting `Type` in `ControlParameter` to `Object`, but the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of `ddlColumns` must be handled in code-behind to use `IN` clause there instead. This is likely a workaround since `ControlParameter` behavior converts supplied value to predefined data type.

Comment: profiler says it executes it like this (which does not error, but gives no returns. `code`exec sp_executesql N'
SELECT * FROM TableData WHERE ColumnID in (@Columns)
',N'@Columns sql_variant',@Columns=N'1,2,3,4,5'`code`

Comment: When I change sql_variant to varchar and run that command in sql manager, it runs well and gives results. But, there is no "type" of varchar in the ControlParameter. :(